# Get camera position and orientation after changing angle 90 degrees

Tags: three.js, camera, rotation, orientation, angle

There is an object in space. Currently I can change the view the object by 90 degrees to an x, y, or z axis. However, the user may tip the object or rotate the object. My desire is to change axis by 90 degrees along an x, y or z axis such that the orientation is preserved.

I have rotated the object in one axis based on the offset of the starting angle and then changed the camera.up position based on the offset of the other axis. This works to some extent but gets very confusing.

Is there a way I can change the camera position (and/or the camera.up vector) more simply?

I am starting with a camera.up vector, a camera.center and a camera.eye. Using these vectors and an angle change of 90 degrees in any of three axes, how would you proceed? Many thanks!

Comment: So you're only ever trying to rotate the camera about an axis, 90 degrees? You basically have a fixed set of 6 positions (not counting rotation permutations and zoom levels)?

Comment: I don't see how you can expect to "preserve the orientation" if the user "tips or rotates" the object.

Comment: Imagine you are looking down on a hockey puck. You can tip the puck front to back, side to side or rotate it. Now imagine you change the vantage point so you are looking from the side (changing your view angle by 90 degrees. There is no zooming in this case.

Comment: The hockey puck is actually a dental model. The user manually orients the model. The side view corresponds to a raycaster angle which analyzes the undercuts and the height of contour of individual teeth AT the orientation that the user selected. Different angles would result in partial denture design variations as well as different paths of insertion.